# How to play system sounds on internal sound card and other sounds on bluetooth audio (win7)

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

On my Windows 7 system is a bluetooth adapter attached which connects to my external bluetooth speakers.

I want to redirect only specific applications (i.e. web radio, spotify) to bluetooth, but all other sounds (Thunderbird, Windows System Sound) should use the internal sound card.

Actually if I connect my BT speaker, all sounds are redirected to that device ...

Answer (score 0):

When you connect two or more sound devices to your computer you can use all of them, either of them or none of them to redirect sound to those devices. Although you can redirect which sounds to direct to those devices by going to ( Taskbar -> Sound Icon -> Mixer) and then select the processes which can redirect sound to the devices.

[image: Sound icon in taskbar]

[image: Volume Mixer]

to select the devices you can right-click to ( Taskbar -> Sound Icon -> Playback Devices ) and then select the devices you want to playback audio on.

Remember all sounds are redirected to the selected devices you simply can't make them play different sound on different devices. like playing (i.e. web radio, spotify) from Bluetooth, and all other sounds (Thunderbird, Windows System Sound) from the internal sound card.